# Filter services when calling Get-Service

Tags: powershell

I did this in the past, and can't remember the correct command (I think I was using instring or soemthign?)

I want to list all the windows services running that have the word 'sql' in them.

Listing all the windows services is:

```
Get-Service
```

Is there a instring function that does this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Get-Service -Name *sql*
```

A longer alternative would be:

```
Get-Service | where-object {$_.name -like '*sql*'}
```

Many cmdlets offer built in filtering and support wildcards.  If you check the help files (Get-Help Get-Service -full), you will see

```
 -name <string[]>
     Specifies the service names of services to be retrieved. Wildcards are
     permitted. By default, Get-Service gets all of the services on the comp
     uter.

     Required?                    false
     Position?                    1
     Default value                *
     Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
     Accept wildcard characters?  true
```

Usually if filtering is built in to the cmdlet, that is the preferred way to go, since it is often faster and more efficient.
In this case, there might not be too much of a performance benefit, but in V2, where you could be pulling services from a remote computer and filtering there would be the preferred method (less data to send back to the calling computer).

Comment: Using just `-Name` doesn't seem to be much performant, how can I include `Display Name` too in the searched fields ? As you see in some Services like `ClickToRunSvc` the actual Name doesn't match the Company whose software has fired the service i.e. `Microsoft Office`, it's `Display Name` is `Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Service`, so how ?

Answer (score 5):

You can get all the services that are running and having words sql.

```
 Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*sql*"}
```

If you want more information, see this (not much difference)
http://nisanthkv.blog.com/2012/06/29/get-services-using-powershell

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

Please enter below command:

```
Get-Service -Name '*<search string>*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are great, but this is more useful:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName <INSERT COMPUTER NAME> -Class Win32_Service | where-object {$_.name -like '*sql*'}
```

It allows for this query on remote computers.

Answer (score 0):

The Search String might be in either Display Name or Service Name (e.g. searching Service Name for `"*SQL*"` does not include the SQL Integration Services ...) so I filter both:

```
get-service | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*MySearchString*" -or $_.ServiceName -like "*MySearchString*"}
```